# wxWidgets, show what is in directory

Tags: directory, icons, wxwidgets

I doing a project using a wxWidgets, and we are doing a sample project of copying 1 or many files (if possible) between 2 folders.

I wish that when I choose a folder (using dirdialog or so) and choose the folder, the contents of it shows in a box at the top of the program (Have the image attached)

Our 2 problems are these.

1) I was planning in using a `wxBoxSizer` or a `wxGridSizer`. Are they most fitting

The biggest problem though is this:

How can we make the FILES of a folder (for example everything inside the C:) as selectible icons simliar to the Windows Explorer. The `DirDialog` only gave us the option to choose the folder, but how to get its contents we wish to know.

If it is not possible, then it's a shame but we do wish to implement since, we if possible we'll implement a filter as well (the one on the RHS)

Thanks

**Down below is the direct link to how our GUI is currently looking**
That blank GREY space should end up where the show file contents should be.

http://s2.postimg.org/fk46h5a49/Capture.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wrapper for [SHGetImageList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in wxWidgets currently, which is really the function you should use under Windows.

But you can use [wxMimeTypesManager::GetFileTypeFromExtension()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_mime_types_manager.html#a20a5bd44120549886911a6bb34a06feb) and then [wxFileType::GetIcon](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_type.html#a5e5a5491cffb54791285663fd337d351) to approximate it -- and this is the best thing you can do for the other platforms anyhow, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: OK I'll see what I can do, otherwise we'll just drop it